Seeking soviet records of Aram Hmayak Kalfyan who died in Siberia in 1943
My maternal grandfather died in Siberia in 1943 Aram Hmayak Kalfyan. I believe he was arrested probably 1927-1930.  I believe he was imprisoned, being a Trotskyte, arrested probably 1927-1930. He had come from Egypt to take a professorship I was told.

What records do you have of your grandfather's birth and prior to the imprisonment/death records that you are asking about here?
